# did select row at indexpath not working after context menu disappears in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicontrol, uicontextmenuinteraction

I am implementing `UIContextMenu` in my App. It runs very well. Only one problem, once context menu has appeared and disappeared, `tableView` delegate `didSelectRowAt` indexPath does not work on first tap, but works on second tap.
I can't seem to find what is causing this. It runs fine in Default Mail app in iPhone. Thus, I think there is something that I might be missing. Help me out.
Response is appreciated.

What I have already tried is reloading `tableView`.
Also could not find anything helpful in the docs.

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let contextMenuConfiguration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { (menuElements) -> UIMenu? in
                let edit = UIAction(title: "Edit", image: UIImage.placeholderIcon) { (action) in
                    print("Edit")
                    self.editInvoice(at: indexPath)
                }
                let preview = UIAction(title: "Preview", image: UIImage.placeholderIcon) { (action) in
                    print("Preview")
                }
                let send = UIAction(title: "Send", image: UIImage.placeholderIcon) { (action) in
                    print("Send")
                }
                let share = UIAction(title: "Share", image: UIImage.placeholderIcon) { (action) in
                    print("Share")
                }
                return UIMenu(title: "", image: UIImage.invoiceIcon, identifier: nil, options: UIMenu.Options.displayInline, children: [edit, preview, send])
            }
            return contextMenuConfiguration
        }
        return nil
    }
```

This is the `tableView` delegate I implemented.
Every thing works fine. All I want is that did select delegate runs on first tap after context menu disappears.

Comment: Found it! It was not working because tableView scroll was disabled. As soon as I enabled it, it started working. So this worked for me. :-)